# Clicking to index.html does not show that rel="canonical" on home page is working

Tags: seo, duplicate-content

I am trying to use link rel="canonical" to ensure that my home page (example.com/index.htm) is not considered as duplicate content with example.com/ (Site is on APACHE server)
Placing

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/" />
```

or

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example/index.htm" />
```

in HEAD section of index.htm does not seem to work. (Tested live by clicking on index.htm links on other pages.)

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The `<link rel="canonical">` tag will not affect how browsers and users interact with your site. Some visiting `http://www.example/index.htm` with a canonical tag of `<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/" />` will not be redirected to `www.example.com`. And that's okay because that's not what supposed to happen. The canonical tag just tells Google which URL to use in their index and to consider the canonical URL for that content.